# How can I create a shared PHP $_SERVER directory to use as an include() path for shared code?

Tags: php, server, directory

At my previous company we had a shared $_SERVER['shared_code_dir'] directory that was usable by all our sites on our server. I know in php you can't use the include() function with an https web address for security reasons. But we had a directory set up that could be used securely. Does anyone know how to set that up? I apologize if this isn't completely clear.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not recommended for security reasons, particularly if it's an internet-facing website because it might get abused if coded improperly, it can be configured!

You'll need to enable **allow_url_include** in your **php.ini** configuration for it to work.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

Comment: Hey Luis. Thank you. I'm aware of that setting, but I was hoping there was a way to create a global $_SERVER variable that's secure without flipping that switch in the php.ini file since I know that is a security risk. Is there any workaround to that variable?

Comment: "it's not recommended for security reasons" - it's also not a very practical solution. URL includes are not intended for including arbitrary PHP scripts. When you include a PHP script using a URL, you are making an HTTP request and consequently including the _output_ (the HTTP response) that the PHP script produces, not the PHP script itself, into the receiving PHP script. Most PHP files (the kind you would want to share in a library of _includes_, such as a group of functions or classes) don't output anything, so the `include(<some-URL>)` statement includes _nothing_.

Comment: ... to include an arbitrary PHP script `X.php` using a URL wrapper, you would need to include a secondary script `Y.php` that fetches `X.php` and returns this in the HTTP response. Or, you use a none `.php` ext for your included files, so they aren't processed at the source server (or disable PHP altogether and have the server serve static resources only). Needless to say, due to the HTTP request, this is going to be slow, so local caching of this file(s) would be required. Anyway, this is all a bit academic. If all sites are on the "same server" there is no need to use URL wrappers.